Updated usage for DependencyInjectionTestFramework
I'm updating my .NET version to .NET 8, so I updated xUnit to the latest version. One of the changes is that DependencyInjectionTestFramework is no longer inheritable.
Some of the parts of the code that changed for me are:
    public class Startup : DependencyInjectionTestFramework

    // and this 
    public Startup(IMessageSink messageSink) : base(messageSink)

    // and this
    protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(AssemblyName assemblyName)
    {
        return base.CreateHostBuilder(assemblyName).ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices);
    }

And now all of my dependency injections are broken. I'm getting a fixture data issue
The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data

The only solution I have found so far is to manually do all of the DI. Is there any way to replicate the old behavior for DependencyInjectionTestFramework
Thank you in advance.

Did you ever find an answer? I'm facing the same thing :(
